# Set valid string prop based on imported object / Programmatically create string literal type

Tags: typescript

I'm converting a React project to use TypeScript, and I have an `Icon` component that takes a prop which is a string, but should to be a valid CSS class name.

The way I handled this with React's PropTypes was

```
Icon.propTypes = {
  icon: oneOf(Object.keys(css)).isRequired,
}
```

is there a way to achieve the same thing in TypeScript without typing out every class name in a string literal type like this?

```
interface Props {
  icon: "class1" | "class2" | ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `css` object is something like:

```
const css = {
    "class1": "something",
    "class2": "something",
    "classN": "something"
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
interface Props {
    icon: keyof typeof css
}

// fine:
let props: Props = {
    icon: "class1"
}
```

But this:

```
let props: Props = {
    icon: "something else"
}
```

Results in an error:

> Type '{ icon: "something else"; }' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
>   Types of property 'icon' are incompatible.
>       Type '"something else"' is not assignable to type '"class1" | "class2" | "classN"'.